# Am I able to edit the text and the image that comes up for my Facebook share button?

Tags: html, facebook, twitter, hyperlink

I'm currently working with social media buttons for the first time, and am having some trouble with the Facebook share button. The Twitter and Pinterest buttons work great, but the Facebook button won't let me add any custom text, and it pulls the first graphic on the webpage to share, and I would like it to pull a custom graphic. Here is the code I currently have in place.

```
 <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=URL">
    <img src="IMAGE" style="display:inline"/>
  </a>
```

If it helps, here are the Twitter and Pinterest codes that are working perfectly:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=TEXT;hashtags=HASHTAGS;url=URL">
    <img src="IMAGE" style="display:inline"/>
  </a>
     <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=URL&amp;description=TEXT&amp;media=IMAGE">
    <img src="IMAGE" style="display:inline"/>
  </a>
```

I need a Facebook code that will fit into the `<a href>` tag so it lines up correctly on the page.

I was directed to another thread, and tried those solutions and they did not work. I am working with a Shopify store, if that helps at all. I have contacted Shopify help, our theme creators help, and tried 20-30 different codes to try to make the share link work correctly with edited text and photo. I could really use the help for the specific code I gave because I am not sure what else to do.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the suggested edits from this threat and none of them have worked, all the do is change my share link to a single text-box with a link of the page, that isn't share-able at all.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook takes the data from the Open Graph Tags, here are some useful links for you:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup
- http://ogp.me/

You can refresh and test OG data in the debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/